# Pass token or username to B2C Edit Policy in MSAL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to figure out if there is a way in MSAL to pass in the current token, or user name to avoid prompting the user for their user name and password (via two textboxes with no labels, just two blank entry boxes, not ideal) before continuing in the Azure AD B2C Edit policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a WebApp, if you've already signed in the user either via the SignIn policy or the SignUp/SignIn, when launching the EditProfile policy, the user, thanks to single sign-on (SSO) should **not** get prompted for a username and password again but should rather go straight to editing their profile.

In the case of a Native client at this time there is no mechanism to pass in the current token or user name (whether using MSAL, some other library or coding to the protocol) to the B2C Edit Profile Policy. Your best bet is to build your own Edit Profile experience and go straight to the Graph API to save the changes.

Here's a sample with more details on how to call the Graph for Azure AD B2C and make updates to a user:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com/users/<user-object-id>?api-version=1.6
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjdkRC1nZWNOZ1gxWmY3R0xrT3ZwT0IyZGNWQSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJod...
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37
{
    "displayName": "Joe Consumer",                // this request updates only the user's displayName
}
```

I'd also recommend creating an entry (or voting for one if it exists) in the [Azure AD B2C UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c) forum requesting way to pass in the username/token as per your original ask